# HREF with SPAN using a pipe delimiter with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="/symptoms/treat-your-childs-headache/">
    <span class="read-more-button">Read More</span>
</a>
```

I have the above code in the view source code and there are multiple buttons with the same name "Read More" without an id.

I want to have the href name with a pipe delimiter once a user clicks on any of the read more links/buttons.

Ex: In the above example, if user clicks on read more, I want to have a value as

```
Read More | /symptoms/treat-your-childs-headache/
```

Completely new to coding and trying to learn. Kindly help. I want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add a click event listener to the `.read-more-button` elements using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.read-more-button').one('click', function() {
    // append the href
    $(this).append(' | ' + $(this).parent().attr('href'));
    // don't follow the link
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/symptoms/treat-your-childs-headache/">
  <span class="read-more-button">Read More</span>
</a>
```